# Problems with deep link in push notifications

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io, localytics

I am using `Branch.IO` to generate deep links. Now the normal flow works perfectly. Opens the application on tapping the link from the notes application.

The problem is when I put the deep link URL in the payload of notification and tap on the notification. It does open the application but it then redirects to app store instantly. What might be the issues any guess? I am facing similar behavior in Android too.

I am sending push notifications using Localytics. Adding Url `ll_deep_link_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here: the `ll_deep_link_url` parameter is from Localytics, and is likely causing a conflict with Branch link handling.

You'll want to see the [Branch documentation for deep links in push notifications](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/deep-link-routing/guide/ios/#branch-links-in-push-notifications) instead.